# How to split strings on carriage return with C#?

Tags: c#, text-manipulation

I have an ASP.NET page with a multiline textbox called txbUserName. Then I paste into the textbox 3 names and they are vertically aligned:

- Jason
- Ammy
- Karen

I want to be able to somehow take the names and split them into separate strings whenever i detect the carriage return or the new line. i am thinking that an array might be the way to go. 
Any ideas?

thank you.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

```
string[] result = input.Split(new string[] {"\n", "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This covers both \n and \r\n newline types and removes any empty lines your users may enter.

I tested using the following code:

```
        string test = "PersonA\nPersonB\r\nPersonC\n";
        string[] result = test.Split(new string[] {"\n", "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string s in result)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```

And it works correctly, splitting into a three string array with entries "PersonA", "PersonB" and "PersonC".

Comment: Is there a guarantee that this wouldn't first split by \n, leaving \r\n reduced to \r?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't. I use this line in my app at work and it's used to parse the clipboard one at a time (somehow users have a need for UNIX line-endings on Windows...). However, if it does, I imagine that reversing the strings in the string array argument would solve this. Does anyone know how to generate a mix of the two to test with?

Comment: @jasonh: "I'm pretty sure"... famous last words. :)

Comment: @jasonh: with tools and apps being used on both Windows and Linux, the lines are being blurred a bit, and in reality any application running on either should be able to handle either line ending gracefully.

Comment: @Esteban Araya: LOL! I revised my answer with test code showing that it passes with flying colors. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot jasonh, your example is just great. I just tested it and it works great. all the strings are ordered in the array in the same order they were entered too.

Comment: @spender: Of course there's a gurantee. You'll get 3x you money back if you get fired by your boss if the code splits the lines incorrectly. :P

Comment: If you want to be sure of splitting on all combinations of CR or LF then you can do this: `string[] result = input.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: If you wish to keep the empty lines, use `string[] result = input.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: In my case, the string sometimes contained \r, so I needed to add that to the Split arguments result = input.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n', '\r\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Answer (score 7):

Replace any `\r\n` with `\n`, then split using `\n`:

```
string[] arr = txbUserName.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split("\n".ToCharArray());
```

Comment: why not use `new char[] { '\n' }` ?

Comment: @Matthew: old habits die hard :P

Comment: @Matthew, @o.k.w: Or even just use `Split('\n')` since the separator array is a `params` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the String.Split function (not sure of exact syntax, no IDE in front of me).

```
string[] names = txbUserName.Text.Split(Environment.Newline);
```

Comment: Environment.Newline is the "newline" representation of the server's environment, it doesn't control what the user can input, does it?

Comment: If a constant could control what the user could input, well I'd buy more Microsoft stock... a *lot* more.

Comment: FWIW - it's better to use "\r" and/or "\n", my answer focuses more on the "just use .split" to break the string up.  Just be glad you don't have to write .split in C and manage the memory and pointers yourself!  Young whipper-snappers got it easy I tell ya.

Answer (score 1):

[`String.Split`?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

```
mystring.Split(new Char[] { '\n' })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


 protected void btnAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = txtDetails.Text;
        char[] delimiter = new char[] { ';','[' };
        string[] parts = value.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            txtFName.Text = parts[0].ToString();
            txtLName.Text = parts[1].ToString();
            txtAge.Text = parts[2].ToString();
            txtDob.Text = parts[3].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
message.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Works if :

```
var message = "test 1\r\ntest 2";
```

Or

```
var message = "test 1\ntest 2";
```

Or

```
var message = "test 1\rtest 2";
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do. Another option, which is probably overkill for small lists, but may be more memory efficient for larger strings, is to use the `StringReader` class and use an enumerator:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetNextString(string input)
{
    using (var sr = new StringReader(input))
    {
        string s;
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

This supports both `\n` and `\r\n` line-endings. As it returns an `IEnumerable` you can process it with a `foreach`, or use any of the standard linq extensions (`ToList()`, `ToArray()`, `Where`, etc).

For example, with a `foreach`:

```
var ss = "Hello\nworld\r\ntwo bags\r\nsugar";
foreach (var s in GetNextString(ss))
{
    Console.WriteLine("==> {0}", s);
}
```