# TextBox Word-Wrapping splitting string to lines

Tags: c#, string, textbox, word-wrap

This is my first time posting question on this amazing service, since today it has helped me a lot by just reading it.

Currently, I'm making small C# application where I need to use a lot of TextBoxes.
In TextBox Properties I have checked **MultiLine** and **Word-Wrap** functions.
So when user enters text, it is displayed correctly in multiple lines.

My problem is how can I get those lines, which are displayed on form, in list of strings, instead of one big string.

I haven yet distinguished weather **Word-Wrap Function** makes new lines or adds "\n\r" at the end of every line.
I tried to get lines from **TextBox.Lines** , but it has only TextBox.Lines[0], which contains the whole string form TextBox

I have already tried many things and researched many resources, but I still  haven't found right solution for this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is a good first question.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6):

Lots of corner cases here.  The core method you want use is `TextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine()`, that lets you iterate the lines after TextBox has applied the WordWrap property.  Boilerplate code:

```
    var lines = new List<string>();
    for (int line = 0; ;line++) {
        var start = textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
        if (start < 0) break;
        var end = textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1);
        if (end == -1 || start == end) end = textBox1.Text.Length;
        lines.Add(textBox1.Text.Substring(start, end - start));
    }
    // Do something with lines
    //...
```

Beware that line-endings are included in *lines*.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get the line count and build an array of lines directly. This is inclusive of lines generated due to WordWrap.

```
// Get the line count then loop and populate array
int lineCount = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox1.Text.Length) + 1;

// Build array of lines
string[] lines = new string[lineCount];
for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
{
    int start = textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);
    int end = i < lineCount - 1 ? 
        textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i + 1) :
        textBox1.Text.Length;                            
    lines[i] = textBox1.Text.Substring(start, end - start);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out the single `string` and then do whatever you want with it.

Splitting a string into a list of strings based on a separator is straightforward:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814568/13895