# Read a big Excel document

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, oledb

I want to know what is the fastest way to read cells in Excel. 
I have an Excel file that contains 50000 rows and I wanna know how to read it fast.
I just need to read the first column and with oledb connection it takes me like 15 seconds.
Is there a faster way?

Thanks

Comment: Is 14 seconds fast enough? Can you skip oledb and convert the sheet to a csv fileand then read the lines from the file? How does your oledb query look like? Has that cell a lot of data? Is it excel OpenXml (aka xlsx)?

Comment: Sorry the excel document is already in .csv.

Comment: if it is already in csv, use a cvs reader: see here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Answer (score 9):

Here is a method that relies on using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Please Note: The Excel file I used had only one column with data with 50,000 entries.

1) Open the file with Excel, save it as csv, and close Excel.

2) Use StreamReader to quickly read the data.

3) Split the data on carriage return line feed and add it to a string list.

4) Delete the csv file I created.

I used System.Diagnostics.StopWatch to time the execution and it took 1.5568 seconds for the function to run.

```
public static List<string> ExcelReader( string fileLocation )
{                       
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook =
        excel.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation);
    workBook.SaveAs(
        fileLocation + ".csv",
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows
    );
    workBook.Close(true);
    excel.Quit();
    List<string> valueList = null;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLocation + ".csv")) {
        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        valueList = new List<string>(
            content.Split(
                new string[] {"\r\n"},
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
            )
        );
    }
    new FileInfo(fileLocation + ".csv").Delete();
    return valueList;
}
```

Resources:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5123/Opening-and-Navigating-Excel-with-C

[How to split strings on carriage return with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814562/how-to-split-strings-on-carriage-return-with-c)

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for this, drastically improved my program

Comment: I think that you can equally use this code `string line = ""
line = sr.ReadLine()` instead of worrying about the `carriage return line feed`

Answer (score 3):

Can you put your code for reading 50000 records using OLEDb provider. I have tried doing that, it took 4-5 seconds to read 50000 records with 3 columns. I have done in following way, just have a look, it may help you out. :)

```
       // txtPath.Text is the path to the excel file
        string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + txtPath.Text + ";" + "Extended Properties=" + "\"" + "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;" + "\"";

        OleDbConnection oleCon = new OleDbConnection(conString);

        OleDbCommand oleCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM [Sheet1$]", oleCon);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        oleCon.Open(); 
        dt.Load(oleCmd.ExecuteReader());
        oleCon.Close();
```

If you can put your code here, so that I can try to rectify. :)

Comment: For a excel file with 50k lines and they want to pick just the first column, this method has been beaten by copying to csv file and using stream reader. But if they want to pick few more columns in a excel file with a lot of columns. I believe people will come with this one.

Answer (score 2):

OLEDB will always take more time.

SQL Server 2005/2008 will make it faster.

For OLEDB connections, it takes 7 records per seconds while

For SQLServer , it takes 70 records per seconds.

There requires not much time in reading comma separated files, but time is required to insert the data.

I have literally experienced this thing.

Comment: How does this help? OP says they want to import CSV and not comparing with SQL Server?

Comment: @Belogix I said, reading requires no time, time is required in inserting that file to database, I am already working on Stock exchange related project wherein i have to deal with large trade files in .csv format and i am doing same operation. Thats why i said it.

Comment: @Freelancer Granted, but OP made no implication that this would be inserted into a database. Just wants to "read cells in Excel". I don't see how SQLServer even comes into the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to read a list of numbers from a file?  Does it have to be in Excel?  Is some non technical person updating the list?  If you want to read 50,000  numbers from a single column in to a list in memory, just copy the cells to a text file and read with a TextReader.  It'll be instant.

```
List<string> ReadFile(string path)
{
   TextReader tr = new StreamReader(path);
   string line;
   List<string> lines = new List<string>();
   while((line=tr.ReadLine())!=null)
   {
       //if this was a CSV, you could string.split(',') here
       lines.add(line);
   }

   return lines;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same thing and i read in the office dev center :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/418ada31-8748-48d2-858b-d177326daa76/export-to-excel-open-xml-sdk-vs-microsoftofficeinteropexcel?forum=oxmlsdk

You have the two choices for manipulating Excel files :

- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel that uses Excel.Application as an added layer for code execution
- Open XML SDK that allows the developer to work directly with the closed file

there isn't much difference between the two but in your case where the performance is an issue you should use the Open XML SDK that may be a bit faster and don't need that much time opening a large file before processing. as you may read also in the link above and i quote :

> Office for automation purposes is not supported. The Office applications were not designed to run without human supervision and have a nasty tendency to "hang"

a good start for learning the open xml sdk is provided in this link :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx